# Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'host:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, teamcity, x11

I'm struggling with an issue with X11 when running a build in TeamCity, the TC agent has X11 installed and when I'm logging in the user executing the build run it works for 1 time else I always get that error:

> Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'host:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

I've tried many solutions found on the web (like export display, using xvfb, or changing java version) that could have solved but none worked and I barely understand why it does work 1 time when I log in the TC user.

I also get a null pointer exception at the end of the run and wonder if both errors are related.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the plugin used is maven-plugin 1.4 and that we have an old Ubuntu14 box that does work on which I copied the files from

```
15:54:35
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:54:35
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
15:54:35
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15:54:35
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
15:54:35
      at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
15:54:35
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15:54:35
    Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'host:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
15:54:35
      at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
15:54:35
      at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
15:54:35
      at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
15:54:35
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
15:54:35
      at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
15:54:35
      at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
15:54:35
      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
15:54:35
      at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
15:54:35
      at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
15:54:35
      at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.createGraphics(BufferedImage.java:1182)
15:54:35
      at org.apache.batik.ext.awt.image.GraphicsUtil.createGraphics(Unknown Source)
15:54:35
      at org.apache.batik.gvt.filter.GraphicsNodeRed8Bit.genRect(Unknown Source)


  Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (generate-theme) on project (project): An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
```

I really do need some help, please!!!

Comment: Do you use ssh X11 forwarding?

Comment: yes when i log in the agent my display is being forwarded but the things is that  i dont need to go on that servers very often and i should not be going everytime tho to make a run for that project

Comment: It works because your X11 server can be reached through ssh.  Run in headless mode.

Comment: i tried running it in headless mode in java but that didnt worked out

Comment: "Didn't work out..." ?

Comment: well i can pass argument in my teamcity build to have java working headless but it dont want to take the argument tho

Comment: Does the code work if you explicity unset the DISPLAY variable?

Comment: nope that stil not go through if i unset the display

Comment: sorry for the long delay  Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen but when i want the build to run in headless mode it keeps on asking for the display .in the teamcity build...also i even tried to create a build step in teamcity project to set the display and this is still asking for the display

Comment: Something is setting your DISPLAY variable incorrectly.  For some reason your setop appears to be broken.

Comment: i don't see why it would be broken as it is doing it on any new agent i've updated to u18 .. that's the weirdest thing i've seen actually